# SSO Possibilities between Mern app and Shopify store

Tags: reactjs, authentication, shopify, mern, okta

I have a MERN application with Auth0-based login, and I also have a Shopify store on a different domain (store.shopy.com). When users log in to my React app, they will see the Shopify icon. Upon clicking the icon, they should be automatically logged in to the Shopify store without requiring any additional login. I know that there is an SSO option available with Auth0, but I'm unable to configure it in Shopify. Is there any better approach available to solve this? Please enlighten me.

Comment: To use SSO with Shopify you need to subscribe to their Plus plan. That is all. The rest is easy.

Comment: @DavidLazar cant i do it without shopify plus?

Comment: Nope. Shopify is a service, and you pay for SSO if you want to use it.